# How do i display Leading Zero on Input type text?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with this code that the first text always ignore 0 on displaying.

Input type text

```
 <input name="contactnumber" type="text" class="form-control" id="contactnumber">
```

JQuery:

```
function editModal(route, name, address, contactnumber, email) {

    $('#name').val(name)
    $('#address').val(address)
    $('#contactnumber').val(contactnumber);
    $('#email').val(email);
    $(".editForm").attr("action", route);
    $(".edit-form").text("Update Supplier : " + name);
  }
```

This is how i currently tried to display the value but it always ignore the first value if 0.

JS:

```
    if(typeof eventDtSource != 'undefined'){
    let $tb = $('#supplier_table').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: eventDtSource,
        autoWidth:false,
        columns: [
            { name: 'name'},
            { name: 'address'},
            { name: 'contactnumber'},
            { name: 'email'},
            { name: 'actions', orderable: false, searchable: false, className: 'action-column'}
        ],
    })
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: `<input type="number" />` OR `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"/>`might be helpful in this case.

Comment: Has to be a string to have a leading zero. You might be losing it by sending it to page as a number or by parsing string to number

Comment: @charlietfl the structure in my database was ```varchar``` and the type of box is ```text``` only and i'm really getting wierd on this one because when i tried it on other textbox it is working but not on this textbox.

Comment: Ok but what is `typeof contactnumber` in your function? Looks like it's a number in your console, not string

Comment: @charlietfl I edited the post with JS I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Check the json sent and see if it contains string or number. Your server code could be converting it when you serialize the rows to json

Comment: @Bapmop Did you try my answer - did that helped in any way ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes i tried it. but nothing happened it is still the same. it is weird.

Comment: @Bapmop Add your json data in the question.